# I can't use OpenCL through Python via ctypes

Tags: python, opencl, ctypes

I am trying to use opencl through python via pythons ctypes library.  On a new machine I am using, nothing is working anymore.  I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\why_like_this.py", line
> 10, in 
> succ = clGetPlatformIDs(1,pIDs,0) OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000000000000

The following is the simple python code that is causing the issue:

```
import ctypes

opencl = ctypes.WinDLL('OpenCL')

clGetPlatformIDs = opencl.clGetPlatformIDs
clGetPlatformIDs.restype = ctypes.c_int32
clGetPlatformIDs.argtypes = [ctypes.c_uint32, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_void_p]

pIDs = (ctypes.c_int64*1)()
succ = clGetPlatformIDs(1,pIDs,0)
```

Comment: The new machine is Windows 10 64 bit.  The version of python is 3.6.5

Answer (score 0):

The issue was bad runtime libraries.  Upon reinstalling video drivers for the system, the error has gone away.